# is there a way to get a list of files based on date?

Tags: delphi

In Delphi, I need to get a list of files from a directory based on date.
my current code is returning all the files requested, using

```
Files := tDirectory.GetFiles(aDir, '*.docx', tSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
```

and I want those files, based on a date (so I don't have to process 20000 files, only the 10 that have been added since the 'last' time I checked...)

is there a way to do this?

Comment: [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw)

Comment: Use one of the overloaded versions of ``TDirectory.GetFiles`` where a ``TFilterPredicate`` parameter is used. Write e.g. an anonymous method for it, where you filter out all unwanted files using the ``SearchRec`` parameter of this anon method. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.TFilterPredicate

Comment: @delphicoder that still iterates over the whole directory

Comment: Which date? Creation, modification, or access? Since filetimes are stored with microseconds it's highly unlikely you ever find an API from the OS that let's you specify a date only. Either look for directory **changes**, or prepare to enumerate all again and again and **filter** by (in your case) [filetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataw).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Your proposed solution is useful for real time monitoring of directory changes. But OP is interested in files added since the last check by date. This means that OP application isn't running all the time meaning your solution won't work for him.

Comment: @silver if the app isn't running the whole time then you'll need to check the whole directory, or read the file system audit logs. Given that this is a feature waiting to be implemented, one solution is to have a process running that calls ReadDirectoryChangesW. I assume that part of the task here is to write new code.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? Just out of curiosity, how long do typical operations on this folder of 20k+ files take? Eg., if you change the sort-by-date order or sort-by-extension? (yes, just in the File Explorer) Also, how old is the oldest file in that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
USES System.Types, System.IOUtils;

FUNCTION GetFilesNewerThan(CONST Path,SearchPattern : STRING ; CONST SearchOption : TSearchOption ; CONST NewerThan : TDateTime) : TStringDynArray;
  BEGIN
    Result:=TDirectory.GetFiles(Path,SearchPattern,SearchOption,
                                FUNCTION(CONST Path : STRING ; CONST SearchRec : TSearchRec) : BOOLEAN
                                  BEGIN
                                    Result:=(SearchRec.TimeStamp>NewerThan)
                                  END);
  END;
```

This calls the TDirectory.GetFiles method but applies a filter so that only files that have a "LastWrite" time later than the given "NewerThan" parameter is returned.

It will still have to read the entire directory structure - there's no built-in way to filter on time stamps if you don't constantly monitor the directory like David suggests (I assume this is a program that is run "on demand" and not a service that runs 24/7).

Comment: Actually, both.  I have a service constantly running that needs to monitor the directory, and if new files are found, it started an application to process the new files.

thanks for the code snip, it's what I was looking for.  (was wondering how that was to be correctly implemented)